# How to get analog output from ultrasonic sensor hc-sr04

Tags: raspbian

I have ultrasonic sensor hc-sr04.
I want to make edge guide (**not distance measuring**)  . So I need analog output from receiver.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This belongs on "Electrical engineering" since its not about Raspberry PI. And I would suggest that you do some research first.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry that analog signal is not available you would have to modify the module. If yours has an analog output you should have posted a link to its technical data.  The HC-SR04 works by broadcasting a high frequency sound waves from the transmitter (miniature speaker) on the module. This sound then bounces off of an object where the some of the sound is reflected back to the receiver where a microphone listens for it. You can calculate how far away something is by the time it takes for the sound waves to get back to the on board microphone. Internally it is received, filtered and the resultant output is passed into a comparator which has histersys which in turn gives you a digital output.

You need to time from when you send the pulse until it is received. Time to travel is dependent on the properties of the media, typically air. This will have small changes depending on temperature, altitude and humidity to name a few. You can search for the HC-SR04 schematic online, there are several available and all that I saw have only digital outputs same as the ones I use.